# Laravel websockets server + nginx + ssl + vps

Tags: javascript, laravel, nginx, websocket, vps

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой задачей:
Нужно запустить Laravel websocket server на VPS хосте. Стоит nginx, есть ssl сертификат.

UPD: в laravel.log при попытке broadcast выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
production.ERROR: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://*site*.me:6001/apps/...
```

Я пробовал достаточно много всего, но пока ничего не получилось. Вот настройка nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; 
    {{ssl_certificate_key}}
    {{ssl_certificate}}
    server_name *site*.me;
    return 301 https://www.*site*.me$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; 
    {{ssl_certificate_key}}
    {{ssl_certificate}}
    server_name www.*site*.me www1.*site*.me;
    {{root}}

    {{nginx_access_log}}
    {{nginx_error_log}}

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        auth_basic off;
        allow all;
    }

    {{settings}}

    location / {
        {{varnish_proxy_pass}}
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_connect_timeout      720;
        proxy_send_timeout         720;
        proxy_read_timeout         720;
        proxy_buffer_size          128k;
        proxy_buffers              4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf|map)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        expires max;
        access_log off;
    }

    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    server_name www.*site*.me www1.*site*.me;
    {{root}}

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index index.php index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS "on";
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 443;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:{{php_fpm_port}};
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "{{php_settings}}";
    }

    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }
}
```

broadcasting.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "ably", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https'
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

        'ably' => [
            'driver' => 'ably',
            'key' => env('ABLY_KEY'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

websockets.php:

```
<?php

use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Dashboard\Http\Middleware\Authorize;

return [

    /*
     * Set a custom dashboard configuration
    //  */
    // 'dashboard' => [
    //     'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
    // ],

    /*
     * This package comes with multi tenancy out of the box. Here you can
     * configure the different apps that can use the webSockets server.
     *
     * Optionally you specify capacity so you can limit the maximum
     * concurrent connections for a specific app.
     *
     * Optionally you can disable client events so clients cannot send
     * messages to each other via the webSockets.
     */
    'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],

    /*
     * This class is responsible for finding the apps. The default provider
     * will use the apps defined in this config file.
     *
     * You can create a custom provider by implementing the
     * `AppProvider` interface.
     */
    'app_provider' => BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Apps\ConfigAppProvider::class,

    /*
     * This array contains the hosts of which you want to allow incoming requests.
     * Leave this empty if you want to accept requests from all hosts.
     */
    'allowed_origins' => [
        //
    ],

    /*
     * The maximum request size in kilobytes that is allowed for an incoming WebSocket request.
     */
    'max_request_size_in_kb' => 5000,

    /*
     * This path will be used to register the necessary routes for the package.
     */
    'path' => 'laravel-websockets',

    /*
     * Dashboard Routes Middleware
     *
     * These middleware will be assigned to every dashboard route, giving you
     * the chance to add your own middleware to this list or change any of
     * the existing middleware. Or, you can simply stick with this list.
     */
    'middleware' => [
        'web',
        Authorize::class,
    ],

    'statistics' => [
        /*
         * This model will be used to store the statistics of the WebSocketsServer.
         * The only requirement is that the model should extend
         * `WebSocketsStatisticsEntry` provided by this package.
         */
        'model' => \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Statistics\Models\WebSocketsStatisticsEntry::class,

        /**
         * The Statistics Logger will, by default, handle the incoming statistics, store them
         * and then release them into the database on each interval defined below.
         */
        'logger' => BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Statistics\Logger\HttpStatisticsLogger::class,

        /*
         * Here you can specify the interval in seconds at which statistics should be logged.
         */
        'interval_in_seconds' => 60,

        /*
         * When the clean-command is executed, all recorded statistics older than
         * the number of days specified here will be deleted.
         */
        'delete_statistics_older_than_days' => 60,

        /*
         * Use an DNS resolver to make the requests to the statistics logger
         * default is to resolve everything to 127.0.0.1.
         */
        'perform_dns_lookup' => false,
    ],

    /*
     * Define the optional SSL context for your WebSocket connections.
     * You can see all available options at: http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php
     */
'ssl' => [
    /*
     * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
     * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
     * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
     * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
     */
    'local_cert' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.**.me/cert.pem',

    /*
     * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for
     * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
     */
    'local_pk' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.**.me/privkey.pem',

    /*
     * Passphrase with which your local_cert file was encoded.
     */
    'passphrase' => null
],
    /*
     * Channel Manager
     * This class handles how channel persistence is handled.
     * By default, persistence is stored in an array by the running webserver.
     * The only requirement is that the class should implement
     * `ChannelManager` interface provided by this package.
     */
    'channel_manager' => \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\Channels\ChannelManagers\ArrayChannelManager::class,
];
```

bootstrap.js:

```
/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

import axios from 'axios';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    forceTLS: true
});

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */
```

Ошибка в консоли:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1/app/09ca3bc9hc243553dfe5?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false' failed:
```

Сам сервер запущен:

```
:/home/**-ssh/htdocs/**# php artisan websockets:serve --host=127.0.0.1
Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...
```

Вполне возможно, что в процессе всех этих попыток тут уже есть какие-то несостыковки. Но я просто не могу понять, как мне добиться работоспособности вебсокет сервера на хосте. На локалке до этого всё работало хорошо

Answer (score 0):

i was also having this issue... what fixed it was changing the host IP to my domain which have the ssl configured from nginx in 80 port ..
i think as the web-socket first connects with a HTTP protocol for the handshake it cant find the ssl if you have set it with your local ip so you need to kind of change some places of your codebase..

```
broadcasting.php:
'host' => 'your domain which is running the app and have an configured ssl ',
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык